# Check if user exists in database before creating a new one

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I´m using firebase and angularfire to create a list of users.
The database structure is this:

[image]

I need to search if a username exists before creating a new one.
the problem is that i´m using automatically generated ids and not creating my own.

how can I search if a particular nickname exists? thanks!

Comment: This has been covered quite frequently already: https://www.google.com/search?q=angularfire+check+if+username+exists Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I prefer social interaction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am in this situation, I will check every nickname.

Below is a simple example.

Actually you should put all nicknames in array and check it at the last.

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference def_nickname= myRef.child("user");
String input_nickname = "mickey";


ValueEventListener listener_nickname = new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (DataSnapshot p : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                 String nickname = p.child("nickname").getValue(String.class);
                 if (input_nickname.equals(nickname)) {
                      [do something]} else { [do something]}
          }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

     };
def_nickname.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener_nickname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about to create your own 'ID', you can do:

```
userReference.child("otherschilds").child("nickname").setValue("mickey");
```

but dont are a good practice.